# What is the correct way to provide mocked NGRX store to an Angular standalone component test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, ngrx, nrwl-nx

I am trying to add a standalone component inside my existing module based NX Angular project and run into problems when trying to run the unit tests. Providing a mocked store for a non-standalone component test is done through `provideMockStore()`, but this does not seem to work for a standalone component.

This component is not bootstrapped as the application, it exists in its own folder and will be imported when needed by multiple different modules.

###### Example component and test

```js
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FeatureStoreModule, // Import feature store module to access selectors/actions
  ],
  selector: 'standalone',
  templateUrl: './standalone.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./standalone.component.scss'],
})
export class StandaloneComponent {
  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  dispatchAction(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(featureStoreAction()); // Dispatch action imported from FeatureStoreModule
  }
}
```

```js
describe('StandaloneComponent', () => {
  let component: StandaloneComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<StandaloneComponent>;
  let store: MockStore;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [StandaloneComponent],
      providers: [provideMockStore()], // Provide a mocked store for component
    }).compileComponents();

    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StandaloneComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

###### Relevant Installed Packages

```json
"@angular/core": "16.2.4",
"@ngrx/effects": "16.0.1",
"@ngrx/entity": "16.0.1",
"@ngrx/router-store": "16.0.1",
"@ngrx/store": "16.0.1",
"jest": "29.4.3",
"jest-preset-angular": "13.1.1",
```

###### The Problem

Running this test throws the error: `NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for _StoreRootModule!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randombly stumbled upon a solution after trying the code from [@AliF50's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77873897/11763719). If I override the component imports and remove the `FeatureStoreModule` (while still providing a mocked store) the tests run as expected.

###### Solution

```js
describe('StandaloneComponent', () => {
  let component: StandaloneComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<StandaloneComponent>;
  let store: MockStore;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [StandaloneComponent],
      providers: [provideMockStore()],
    })
      // ######### Solution #########
      .overrideComponent(TestComponent, {
        remove: { imports: [FeatureStoreModule] },
      })
      // ############################
      .compileComponents();

    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StandaloneComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

###### Research

I could not find any source that did exactly what I am trying to do (test a standalone component that imports a feature store module). Nor any documentation on this particular case, **nor** if I'm "supposed" to do it this way.

None of the sources I found was importing any store modules in the actual component. They were often bootstrapping the standalone component and providing/registering one or two states in root, **or** they imported providers and registered a feature state through routes.

```js
// Bootstrapping the standalone component and providing/registering states in root
bootstrapApplication(StandaloneComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(
      StoreModule.forRoot({
        stateOne: reducerOne,
        stateTwo: reducerTwo,
      })
    )
  ],
  // ...
})
```

```
// Importing providers and registering a feature state through routes
export const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    providers: [
      importProvidersFrom(
        StoreModule.forFeature('oneState', reducerOne),
        // ...
      ),
    ],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: StandaloneComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Some of the links I visited:

- [Using NgRx Packages with Standalone Angular Features](https://dev.to/ngrx/using-ngrx-packages-with-standalone-angular-features-53d8)
- [Testing Angular Standalone Components](https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/testing-angular-standalone-components/)
- [Standalone API in module-based apps](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#standalone-api-in-module-based-apps)
- [Testing Angular 16 standalone components with Jest](https://blog.stackademic.com/testing-angular-16-standalone-components-with-jest-c79ce3232c8b)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely for a standalone component for testing, we have to take advantage of the `overrideComponent`.

Can you try the following to see if it will work (follow comments with !!)?

```
describe('StandaloneComponent', () => {
  let component: StandaloneComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<StandaloneComponent>;
  let store: MockStore;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [StandaloneComponent],
      providers: [provideMockStore()], // Provide a mocked store for component
    })
    // !! Add overrideComponent here
    .overrideComponent(StandaloneComponent, {
      // !! set the providers.
      set: {
        providers: [provideMockStore()]
      },
      // !! Remove the feature store module
      remove: {
        imports: [FeatureStoreModule]
      }
    })
    .compileComponents();
    
    // !! Not sure if the below line will work.
    // store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
    

    // !! Try getting the store like this, from the component first
    // before going to the root injector
    store = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MockStore);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StandaloneComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately following your suggesting gave the error `Cannot set and add/remove DecoratorFactory at the same time!`, pointing to the `.compileComponents()` line. I was not able to solve this as well; I couldn't find any others with this problem.

Comment: I see them being tested here: https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/testing-angular-standalone-components/ and here https://blog.stackademic.com/testing-angular-16-standalone-components-with-jest-c79ce3232c8b. I think you need to change your `FeatureStoreModule` to `Using NgRx Modules with Standalone Angular APIs` here: https://dev.to/ngrx/using-ngrx-packages-with-standalone-angular-features-53d8. Then maybe your way will work with `provideMockStore`.

Comment: Solution found, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77879069/11763719). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!